# tkinter gui crashes when inserting a large amount of data in scrolledtext

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working with the python tkinter GUI. The problem with me is that the thinter gui hangs when I insert a large amount of data( greater than 200 KB) in ScrolledText widget. Is there any solution to handle a large amount of data with tkinter GUI??

here is my code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import * 
import tkFileDialog
from tkMessageBox import showinfo, showerror 
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText 
import codecs
import random

class GUI_Window():
    '''
        GUI Class 
    '''
    def init(self):        
        self.__m_top = Tkinter.Tk()


        self.lab1 = Tkinter.Label(self.__m_top, font = "{Courier} 10 {bold}" ,text = "Data")
        self.lab1.pack()
        self.lab1.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=25, width=40,x=10,y=20)

        self.__i_txtnm="Data Window"
        self.__Data_window_txt = ScrolledText(self.__m_top, undo=False,height=5,width=4)
        self.__Data_window_txt['font'] = ('Times New Roman', '10')
        self.__Data_window_txt.bind("<Control-Key-a>", lambda event, arg=self.__i_txtnm: self.__select_alldata(event, arg))
        self.__Data_window_txt.pack(expand=False, fill='both')
        self.__Data_window_txt.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE,height=450,width=400,x=10,y=40)


        self.lab1 = Tkinter.Label(self.__m_top, font = "{Courier} 10 {bold}" ,text = "Data Size")
        self.lab1.pack()
        self.lab1.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=25, width=100,x=100,y=500)


        self.tfield = Tkinter.Text(self.__m_top,font = "{Courier} 10 {normal}",width = 82,height = 20,background = 'white', foreground = 'black')
        self.tfield.pack()
        self.tfield.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=25, width=90,x=190,y=500)

        self.lab2 = Tkinter.Label(self.__m_top, font = "{Courier} 10 {bold}" ,text = "KB")
        self.lab2.pack()
        self.lab2.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=25, width=20,x=290,y=500)


        self.__btnText="Generate Data"
        self.__gen_Data_btn=Tkinter.Button(self.__m_top, text = "Generate Data", command =lambda: self.__generate_btn_click() , width = 10)
        self.__gen_Data_btn.pack()
        self.__gen_Data_btn.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=25, width=90,x=140,y=550)

        self.__btnText="Clear Data"
        self.__gen_Data_btn=Tkinter.Button(self.__m_top, text = "Clear Data", command =lambda: self.__claerData() , width = 10)
        self.__gen_Data_btn.pack()
        self.__gen_Data_btn.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=25, width=90,x=240,y=550)


        self.__m_top.wm_title('My Data Window')
        self.__m_top.geometry("450x650")
        self.__m_top.resizable('0', '0')
        self.__m_top.mainloop()
        #self.__browse_sendFilepath_txt.insert(INSERT,file.name)



    def __generate_btn_click(self):

        data_Size=self.tfield.get("1.0", END)
        try:
            data_Size= int(data_Size)
            data=self.__genrateData(data_Size)
            self. __Data_window_txt.insert(INSERT, data)
        except:
            showerror('Set Config', 'Plesase Insert Numeric Value')

    def __select_alldata(self,event,i_txtnm):
            self.__Data_window_txt.tag_add(SEL, "1.0", END)
            self.__Data_window_txt.mark_set(INSERT, "1.0")
            self.__Data_window_txt.see(INSERT)


    def __genrateData(self,i_size):  

        data=''
        for i in range(1024*i_size):
            data+=random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

        return data

    def __claerData(self):
        self.__Data_window_txt.delete(1.0, END)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g1=GUI_Window()
    g1.init()
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit of code? How do you insert the text, via code, or by copy-paste? Just tried this using one of my Tkinter GUIs with `ScrolledText`. Can not reproduce.

Comment: 200k is not really all that much text. The scrolled text widget should handle that and plenty more. There must be more to the problem than you're telling us. By any chance are you doing this from a thread?

Comment: Actually after inserting data above 100 KB, the GUI gets slower and with increase in data it gets hanged when you drag the gui or do scroll in window..

Comment: It could be because you aren't inserting any newlines. I can see how a single line of 200k characters might cause problems. Could you do an experiment and add a linebreak every so often to see what effect that has? I'm not saying that's the final solution, I'm just suggesting this as a way to isolate what the problem might be.

Comment: btw: there is no reason to call `pack` if the very next line calls `place`. Only one geometry manager is ever controlling any given widget, so the `pack` calls are useless. There's also no compelling reason to use `lambda` in your `command` attributes, since you aren't passing any arguments to the functions. You can simplify your code by doing for example: `..., command=self.__claerData`

Comment: yes, I have Tried using '\n' after every 25 characters and it worked.. but as per my requirement I cant insert \n in the data because it changes the interpretation of my data(and sometimes I work with binary data so i cant insert \n in binary).. is there any other way to solve the problem??

Comment: also I work with base64 encoded Data which cannot contain \n character..please help me to solve this problem..